# Jquery .load() and page refreshes

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with this for the last 2 days. I have a drop down that uses autocomplete for Ids. That works fine. When an Id is selected, I'm trying to get it to load a small table that is displayed with the Id information (the `onSelect` portion below).

However when the Id is selected, the page is refreshed, as if I clicked on a link. I realize this is probably something small, I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
var options, a;

$(document).ready(function(){
    options = { 
        serviceUrl:'jsonExceptionRequest.cfm',
        onSelect: function(value, data){
                    $("#claimData").load('ajaxExceptionRequest.cfm?Id=' + value);
                }
        };
    a = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
    return false;
});

<span id="claimData"></span>
```

Comment: Why are you returning false at the end of $(document).ready ?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `return flase;` inside the `onSelect` block.

Comment: Found the problem.  The page "ajaxExceptionRequest.cfm" had debugging on the bottom of it.  When I pulled that into my main page, it must have had code within it that redirected the browser.  I removed all debugging, and everything is working fine now.